# Is there any solution out there that is as easy to use as power query but handles 2gb of data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, microsoft-excel, analytics

I created an excel sheet that using power query and vba generates access keys and makes api calls to my crm to download all data. Unfortunately excel in desktop doesn't allow me to make the data accessible via web or app so employees can all real time analyze the data and i dont have a way to schedule data updates automatically.

I tried azure sql and its very convoluted . I cant even figure out how to download the data or where i would access it. I have no idea how to decipher the pricing puzzle or what features are ideal for this relatively small load of data.

to be clear
-i need to be able to make api calls on a schedule
-hold that information in a table at low cost(30-50 a month)
-access that information from a web analytics tool like power bi
-as far as easy to use, what i'm looking for is something with a community as helpful as excels.

Answer (score 1):

For the kind of scenario you are describing I would like to recommend you [Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs), this is a fully managed service focused on work and process with big loads of data and has different use cases for example, analytics data warehouse and machine learning.

[Since Big Query costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) depends of the amoun of data procesed, this is a very good option with a price of $0.020 per GB being  the first 10 Gb free, just keep in mind that the costs may are different depending from the zone you are working.

Finally Big Query can read the data from different sources, for the use case described by you sounds that load data from [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage) will be a good opcion for you use case.